# Can we pass PUT,PATCH and DELETE request via route() method from blade in anchor tag?

Tags: laravel, http, http-verbs, laravel-6.2

**Rephrasing Question** : I know how it works via form submit and ajax request, i've been looking that if there is any way we can send "DATA", simply by calling URL (mentioned below) for **PUT,PATCH and DELETE** and **csrf** token will be taken from **Kernel > Middleware** not via form submit.

I've been trying to use this method `destroy()` DELETE method to be run from blade file like this

`<a class="p-2" href="{{ route('employees.destroy',[$key->id]) }}">Remove</a>`

Can we override this method ?

```
if (! function_exists('route')) {
    /**
     * Generate the URL to a named route.
     *
     * @param  array|string  $name
     * @param  mixed  $parameters
     * @param  bool  $absolute
     * @return string
     */
    function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
    {
        return app('url')->route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
    }
}
```

This is how i'm calling route

```
Route::resource('employees','EmployeeController');
```

I can do this to achieve what i want

```
Route::get('employees/{employees}','EmployeeController@destroy')->name('employees.destroy');
Route::resource('employees','EmployeeController')->except([
    'destroy'
]);
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Delete method must always need to pass like form submit. You cant directly pass the delete route from the anchor. This is the need to be done because every route needs to pass through `csrf()` which you cant give in anchor tag. Please refer below answer.

Comment: No i mean like passing csrf token , and method name like "DELETE" as in paramaters of default laravel route() method

Comment: ok @Vipertecpro. But usually, this is the most accepted method mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

Might be your solution:

```
<form action="{{ route('employees.destroy', ['id' => $key->id]) }}" method="post">
    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Delete" />
    @method('delete')
    @csrf
</form>
```